# Fiber summation of symplectic Lefschetz fibrations.

Tags: differential-geometry

Recall the following standard result.

> **Theorem:** For any genus $2$ symplectic Lefschetz fibration $f:X\to S^2$, there exists an integer $n_0$ such that, for all $n\ge n_0$, $f\# nf_0$ is isomorphic to a holomorphic fibration.

In fact, given two genus $2$ symplectic Lefschetz fibrations $f,f'$ with
the same numbers of singular fibers of each type (irreducible, reducible
with genus $1$ components, reducible with components of genus $0$ and $2$),
for all large $n$ the fiber sums $f\#nf_0$ and $f'\#nf_0$ are isomorphic. More generally, as a corollary of a recent result of Kharlamov and Kulikov about braid monodromy factorizations, a similar result holds for all Lefschetz fibrations with monodromy contained in the hyperelliptic mapping class group. This leads to the following questions relative to the classification of symplectic $4$-manifolds up to stabilization by fiber sums:

> **Question:** Does every symplectic Lefschetz fibration become isomorphic to a holomorphic fibration after repeatedly fiber summing with certain standard holomorphic fibrations?